# Calculate Omega² and partial Omega² in mixed-Anova

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models

I'm analysing data in a mixed design, having 1 between and 1 within factor using `aov_car()` from the `afex` package.

I tried using `anova_stats()` from the `sjstats` package, which works perfectly fine for within- or between-designs but throws the error:

```
Fehler in UseMethod("anova") : 
nicht anwendbare Methode für 'anova' auf Objekt der Klasse "Anova.mlm" angewendet
```

Error in English (Google Translate):

```
Error in UseMethod ("anova"):
non-applicable method for 'anova' applied to object of class "Anova.mlm"
```

indicating Problems with the returned datatype of `aov_car()`

```r
library(sjstats)
library(afex)
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1:24), each = 4),
              list = rep(c(1:4), 24),
              prop = rnorm(96, 0.8, 0.2),
              treatment = rep(c(1:4), each = 24))
data$treatment <- as.factor(data$treatment)
data$list <- as.factor(data$list)

testAov <- aov_car(prop~list*treatment + Error(ID/list), data=data, return = "Anova")
anova_stats(testAov)
```

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me out with this!

Information about my system and R Version:

```
    R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)  
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
    Running under: Arch Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what was wrong. The `return` in `aov_car()` must be set to `"aov"`. 
So it worked for me using this code:

```
testAov <- aov_car(prop~list*treatment + Error(ID/list), data=data, return = "aov")
anova_stats(testAov)
```